# Remember breakpoints in browser debbuger when the script has parameters (Either Firefox or Chromium)

Tags: php, html, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

So I have this code in php in order to avoid caching:

```html
<script src="urlofthescript?v=<?php echo rand(); ?"></script>
```

But when I'm debugging and assign breakpoints to any line of the script the browser deletes them because it detects the file as a new one, any way to avoid this, or my only option is to just not put the random string, which I'm technically not allowed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using rand() to tell the browser not to cache the file ever - why not fingerprint the file in some manner. Perhaps using the [md5_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) function.

That way whenever the file actually changes so too would the md5 hash. But if the file is unchanged browsers can cache away.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but yeah, that should work. Thanks